# Completion for ++flags in command-line mode

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

Is there any way to turn on tab completion for the various `++[flag]` flags that some commands take?

For example, `:e ++ff=unix whatever.txt` overrides `fileformat` to `unix` for `whatever.txt`, but `:e ++<Tab>` just starts doing file completion for me.

Single-plus completion for something like `:new +<Tab>` works fine for me, but not double plus `:term ++cur<Tab>`.

Comment: Probably this is most easily done at the Vim source level

Comment: Why the bounty? Vim doesn't provide what you want, end of the story. If you want that feature, open an issue in Vim's issue tracker or, better, code it yourself and submit a patch.

Comment: I put a bounty on it because I hadn't gotten any answers or comments yet, affirmative or negative. I didn't think that **silence** was an authoritative answer either way.  Before I go to the trouble of putting in a issue or patch, it seemed worth it to check if I was just ignorant with a community of people who would be able to confirm the presence or absence of such a feature.